# FullCalendar and recurring events (rrule plugin): exdate does not exclude days using a different format

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, rrule

According to the [official doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin) of FullCalendar, you can use the key `exdate` (`rrule` plugin) to exclude a specific day from a recurring event pattern. This is my case:

```
         [
                    {
                        "title": "Foo",
                        "rrule": {
                            "freq": "weekly",
                            "byweekday": ["TH"],
                            "dtstart": "2020-01-01T08:00:00",
                        },
                        "duration": {"minutes": 600},
                        "exdate": ["2021-01-21"],
                    }
          ]
```

But such a piece of code does not work (i.e., I can still see the recurring event `Foo` on `2021-01-21`). The only way to fix I've found so far is using the same date and time format I used in `dtstart`. I.e., `"exdate": ["2021-01-21T08:00:00"]`.

Is there a way to specify an exclusion just using the date string `"2021-01-21"`.

Comment: You could try [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Can you kindly expand your hint?

Comment: Basically, use `dtstart.includes(exdate) !== -1` in an `if` statement. If the function returns -1, `exdate` was not found inside of `dtstart`. If it does not return -1, then `exdate` was found and the number returned would be the index inside of the string. If you read through MDN document I provided, it will be better explained with more examples.

Comment: Thanx @Rojo but it looks like we are speaking about different things. I do not need string processing, I'm just wondering how to make `rrule` plugin works with `FullCalendar` using different date formats.

Comment: Have you tried `2021-01-21T00:00:00`?

Comment: Hey @ADyson. Yep, tried but it did not work

Comment: You'd maybe have a raise a ticket on fullCalendar's github site about this then, to see how they treat the values internally, and whether what you want ought to be supported or not, because it's not explicit in the docs. It appears to consider `"2021-01-21"` to be a different date to `"2020-01-01T08:00:00"`. I don't know if that's intentional or not. We can't help you with issues within fullCalendar here really, you need to speak to the project directly. Details here https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/6105